# Connect Asp membership 4.5.2 to existing ASP membership 4.0 SQL DB

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-membership

I have an ASP project that is using .net framework 4.0 and using membership. I made a new project with framework 4.5.2 using membership on another DB.
Now I want to connect the 4.5.2 project to the old membership DB but it always gives me wrong password as if I wrote the password wrong.
I know the old membership DB have hashpassword and passwordsalt while the new doesn't but what is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You should look at your web.config. In your project with .NET 4.5.2 you have to define your password format as hashed. Use this property

> passwordFormat="Hashed"

Example of membership provider definition in the web.config:

```
 <membership defaultProvider="SqlProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="SqlProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" 
         connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" 
         applicationName="/" 
         enablePasswordRetrieval="false" 
         enablePasswordReset="true" 
         requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" 
         requiresUniqueEmail="false" 
         passwordFormat="Hashed" 
         minRequiredPasswordLength="5" 
         passwordAttemptWindow="30" 
         minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"/>
  </providers>
</membership>
```